# User is not prompted to authenticate after restarting the server

Tags: spring-security

Spring security has been used for our application. Spring security has been configured in bean declaration way.

The problem is : I logged into the application, browsed few pages, and restarted the server(but didn't close the browser). After restarting the server I could successfully move to other pages. I am sure it is not the browser cache as I delete all the cookies before I start go through other pages.

Why does it happen like this ? Is this the default behavior ? How can I enforce the authentication after restarting the server ?

Comment: What makes you sure it's not the browser cache? Usually the browser caches the authentication data for basic authentication.

Comment: Before traversing the pages after the server restart, I clear the browser cookies. Here am pointing to form based authentication (not the basic authentication)

Comment: Are you using HTTP basic auth ? That isn't stored in cookies

Comment: But am having problem in form based authentication (am not concerned about basic authentication for time being)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We use Tomcat 6, and it is the default behavior of the tomcat which serializes sessions before server shutdown and de-serializes next time the server is restarted thus it maintains the session.

If we don't want this default behavior then uncomment the 'Manager' element section in the context.xml.