# Strange behavior of log on after restart application pool

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am building a simple asp.net mvc3 application using Form authentication. After publishing it to IIS 7.5, I find that even after I restart the application pool for my web site(stop it and then start). A logined user doesn't need to re-login. That's not what I expect and I don't remember I had configured the cookie to be persistent.

I use the simple asp.net mvc3 web application template and haven't done much thing to config authentication. Below is some codes related to authentication:

in web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

in LogOn action:

```
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, false);
```

Comment: did you try to reset your iis through command prompt?

Comment: @CodeSpread, yes, same result

Comment: you are creating a cookieless authentication so cookie might not be a problem here. Then the loggedin info might be available in url. check if there is any info getting appended to url.

Comment: @CodeSpread I'm not sure why you think the authentication is cookieless, care to explain?

Comment: @SergeBelov, I was thinking of cookieless authentication as one of the reasons. yes,you are correct, information provided is not sufficient for my reasoning.

Comment: @CodeSpread, no, I'm not using cookieless. ASP.NET_SessionId and .ASPXAUTH are passed in request cookie header. Nevertheless, I think using cookieless should not pass authentication after restart either. I don't know any other configs about authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have got your answer, cookie is set at client side and resetting server IIS will not destroy the cookie as it is not available on server. You can set cookie expiration time and it will get destroy at client side.I hope this clears the situation.

Comment: Yes, after tracking the request I found cookie is passed to server. I just wonder how does the server recognize the cookie value such as .ASPXAUTH and pass the authentication automatically after restart. Shouldn't that info be stored in memory?

Comment: This information is passed to achieve client side state management.

Comment: And how does web server know which user is accessing after restart given cookie like "Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=yhpnitwhfw1twayhs0q0xtm1; .ASPXAUTH=15B183B732C9D050868C55F61A6EC8186EC702D921EEDF9BD33559EB22CCBA10A21B33FBEFD58D169140194B3F3B3CF2F538315090BD1258B5AA201BFC1F5625CACC7D3CCE09E695B57E4A8238FBFA5A"?

Comment: When the request comes from client, request gets appended with session id and other information by reading the cookie stored at client machine.

Comment: So this is the default behavior of ASP.NET right? Can you give me some links of doc to describe how does it work? Thanks. I just want to know what happens when the server restart and a client sends a request, with cookie headers .

Comment: Yes This is the default behaviour, I don't have the link right now but you can search for similar article on codeproject.com. I remember one article is written by shivprasadkoirala over there in an explained manner.

Comment: I am still not very clear about the authentication process. I just see "Set-Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=48BD1BB11EAD74F65F303F593DBA8403E1CBECACD38BF03C7D105AFE046D91AEEC527047D1CA2450A36514E173A696736867A0385C474B369F22D7045FE8EB6BDFF2803B61C604E513C5AB60D1B69421; path=/; HttpOnly" after logon. And I think the auth info is stored on server. Still thanks for your answer. I'll read some article talking about it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20305/discussion-between-codespread-and-chris-lee)

Comment: Based on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550820/user-is-not-prompted-to-authenticate-after-restarting-the-server, I think IIS does the same thing(serialize the session) as Tomcat.

Comment: Yes, Serialization is required to send the data between server and client